# Dovecot not listening on imap and pop3 ports

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, dovecot, sasl

Before I continue, I have looked at tons of posts online about saying that the protocols are not setup, and have tried what they have offered, but all of them do not help, and don't seem to resolve the issue.

I am having some issues, with setting up dovecot. I have been following this guide: http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-mail-server-ubuntu-14-04/ to setup a mail server, and it was all working. Postfix is installed and configured correctly. As I was doing the Dovecot installation, it asked me about using telnet to connect and verify the connections were working (in the guide) and whether ports: **110,995,993,143** work. But only ports **995** and **993** allow me to connect, but they do not show any kind of: '+OK Dovecot (Ubuntu) ready.' on them.

I see this in /var/log/mail.log:

```
Jun 26 09:05:07 master: Info: Dovecot v2.2.9 starting up (core dumps disabled)
Jun 26 09:05:07 config: Warning: service auth { client_limit=1000 } is lower than required under max. load (6000)
Jun 26 09:05:07 config: Warning: service anvil { client_limit=1000 } is lower than required under max. load (6003)
```

Even when I connect to the **993** and **995** ports. When I try the other ones, I just get:

```
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

The process is running, and I can't see no errors. This is the output of **dovecot -n**

```
# 2.2.9: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
doveconf: Warning: service auth { client_limit=1000 } is lower than required under max. load (6000)
doveconf: Warning: service anvil { client_limit=1000 } is lower than required under max. load (6003)
# OS: Linux 3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 x86_64 Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS 
auth_mechanisms = plain login
default_process_limit = 2000
first_valid_uid = 0
imap_idle_notify_interval = 4 mins
listen = * ::
log_path = /var/log/mail.log
mail_access_groups = spampd
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mail_privileged_group = mail
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Archive {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Archive
  }
  mailbox Drafts {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox INBOX {
    auto = subscribe
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Spam {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
plugin {
  antispam_allow_append_to_spam = yes
  antispam_backend = pipe
  antispam_pipe_program = /bin/bash
  antispam_pipe_program_notspam_args = /usr/local/bin/sa-learn-pipe.sh;--ham
  antispam_pipe_program_spam_args = /usr/local/bin/sa-learn-pipe.sh;--spam
  antispam_spam_pattern_ignorecase = SPAM
  antispam_trash_pattern_ignorecase = trash;Deleted *
  fts = lucene
  fts_lucene = whitespace_chars=@.
  sieve = /home/user-data/mail/sieve/%d/%n.sieve
  sieve_after = /home/user-data/mail/sieve/global_after
  sieve_before = /etc/dovecot/sieve-spam.sieve
  sieve_before2 = /home/user-data/mail/sieve/global_before
  sieve_dir = /home/user-data/mail/sieve/%d/%n
}
postmaster_address = postmaster@mail.dannysmc.com
protocols = imap pop3 imap pop3
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 0
  }
}
service lmtp {
  inet_listener lmtp {
    address = 127.0.0.1
    port = 10026
  }
}
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
    port = 0
  }
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </home/user-data/ssl/ssl_certificate.pem
ssl_cipher_list = TLSv1+HIGH !SSLv2 !RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !3DES @STRENGTH
ssl_key = </home/user-data/ssl/ssl_private_key.pem
ssl_protocols = !SSLv3 !SSLv2
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
protocol lmtp {
  mail_plugins = " sieve"
}
protocol imap {
  mail_max_userip_connections = 20
  mail_plugins = " antispam"
}
protocol pop3 {
  mail_plugins = " antispam"
}
```

If you need any more information then just say, any help is appreciated. Because I have reached the end trying to configure this thing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ports 993 and 995 require SSL/TLS, you cannot simply telnet to them and expect things to be printed in clear text. Use something like `openssl s_client -quiet -connect youdomain.tld:993` or `openssl s_client -quiet -connect youdomain.tld:995`
2. `protocols = imap pop3 imap pop3` <- Why do you list them twice?
3. `inet_listener imap { port = 0 }` <- There you disable IMAP on port 143 which is why you cannot telnet to that port. Don't disable IMAP, simply use `disable_plaintext_authentication=yes` if you want to have TLS secured logins.
4. `inet_listener pop3 { port = 0 }` <- There you disable POP3 on port 110 which is why you cannot telnet to that port. Don't disable POP3, simply use `disable_plaintext_authentication=yes` if you want to have TLS secured logins.

By the way, you enable imap and pop3 protocols and have some configuration for lmtp, but you don't enable the lmtp protocol.

Comment: There is no reason to disable imap and pop3 ports. Clients can use STARTTLS to negotiate TLS connection over plaintext port. `disable_plaintext_authentication=yes` prevents users trying to authenticate without TLS/SSL.

Comment: My answer about disabling IMAP and POP3 was related to his config. OP is asking why he cannot telnet to 143 or 110 and I was pointing out which lines in his config are responsible for him not being able to do so. ;) I am by no means supporting that.

Comment: In my understanding it should be `disable_plaintext_auth` instead of `disable_plaintext_authentication`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case when I upgraded from Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10, it somehow got rid of 2 necessary packages.

These are the packages I had after the upgrade:

```
> dpkg -l | grep dovecot
ii  dovecot-core                          1:2.3.4.1-5ubuntu3                     amd64        secure POP3/IMAP server - core files
ii  dovecot-sieve                         1:2.3.4.1-5ubuntu3                     amd64        secure POP3/IMAP server - Sieve filters support
```

So I ran these commands:

```
> sudo apt-get install dovecot-imapd dovecot-pop3d
> sudo service dovecot restart
```

Now when I run `netstat -lntp` I can see listeners for all the ports I expect to see.